# Snapping annotation leader lines to line feature endpoints using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, snapping, annotation, leader-line

I am currently running ArcGIS Pro 2.6. I am attempting to snap the ends of annotation leader lines to line feature endpoints. When I snap them onto the endpoints while somewhat zoomed out they appear to be close to the endpoints, but when I zoom in they're significantly off.

I've tried messing around with the snapping tolerance, but even when I set to something like 5 map units (meters), I find that it snaps to a point more than 5 meters from the actual point its meant to be snapping to.

Am I missing something here, or is this a known bug for ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2):

After some more fiddling around, it seems this issue only appears when using a reference scale. I disabled my reference scale (I was at 1:15,000) and the snapping works just fine. Seems something in the reference scale messes with the system's ability to accurately pinpoint a specific spot. Still seems like it could be a bug, but disabling the reference scale is a suitable workaround for my process.